# ActiveMQ 5.15.3 shows 0 producerCount in the web console

Tags: activemq-classic

Producer count in the activemq web console shows **0**  all the time, even if there are producers connected to the broker. I'm not sure why?

[image]

[image]

My producer code looks like this.

```
public boolean postMessage(List<? extends JMSMessageBean> messageList, String data, int messageCount)
        throws JMSException {
    String queueName = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        connection = pooledConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.setExceptionListener(this);
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        int index = 0;
        for (JMSMessageBean message : messageList) {
            if (producer == null || !message.getQueueName().equals(queueName)) {
                queueName = message.getQueueName();
                producer = getQueueProducer(queueName, session);
            }

            Message _omessage = session.createObjectMessage(message);
            _omessage.setStringProperty("MESSAGE_INDEX", messageCount + ":" + index);
            _omessage.setIntProperty("RETRY_COUNT", 0);
            _omessage.setJMSType(message.getJmsType());
            if (data != null) {
                _omessage.setStringProperty("RAW_DATA", data);
            }
            producer.send(_omessage);
            index++;
        }

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("Exception while creating connection to jms broker", e);

    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != session) {
                session.close();
            }
            if (null != connection) {
                connection.close();
            }
            if(null != producer) {
                producer.close();
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Am using a pooledconnectionfactory to create sessions, connections, and messageproducers. Everytime, someone has to post a message, a new connection is requested from the pooledconnectionfactory. and then

Comment: If I don't use a PooledConnectionFactory, then I can see the producerCount to be positive. But I need to use the PooledConnectionFactory API. Can anyone help, what to do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ActiveMQ client often uses what they call "dynamic producers"-- a producer per message for non-transacted sessions. If you walked the JMS object lifecycle, you'd find there is little need to keep a producer object around in a non-transacted session-- which is different from the consumer object.

Look under the dynamicProducers list in JMX, and you'll catch them being created. You can also monitor the advisory topics to see them get created and destroyed.

Side note: your object close order in the finally is incorrect.. you should close objects in reverse order-- producer, session, connection.